# I can't use summary functions on penguins from the PalmerPenguins package with R

Tags: r

I'm learning R through the Google Analytics Certification and I get stuck on the summary command in R. I'm using Rstudio for this.

We first load the palmerpenguins package and then have to enter the command summary(penguins). The problem is I keep getting an error message as follow:

```
> install.packages("palmerpenguins", lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library")
package ‘palmerpenguins’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

> summary(penguins)
Error in summary(penguins) : object 'penguins' not found
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: you didn't call the installed package which is including the dataset your desire to achive. you need to run `library(palmerpenguins)` first.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that and it wasn't explicit in the course. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to load the package, base function `data` has a `package` argument.

```r
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")
summary(penguins)
#>       species          island    bill_length_mm  bill_depth_mm   flipper_length_mm  body_mass_g       sex           year     
#>  Adelie   :152   Biscoe   :168   Min.   :32.10   Min.   :13.10   Min.   :172.0     Min.   :2700   female:165   Min.   :2007  
#>  Chinstrap: 68   Dream    :124   1st Qu.:39.23   1st Qu.:15.60   1st Qu.:190.0     1st Qu.:3550   male  :168   1st Qu.:2007  
#>  Gentoo   :124   Torgersen: 52   Median :44.45   Median :17.30   Median :197.0     Median :4050   NA's  : 11   Median :2008  
#>                                  Mean   :43.92   Mean   :17.15   Mean   :200.9     Mean   :4202                Mean   :2008  
#>                                  3rd Qu.:48.50   3rd Qu.:18.70   3rd Qu.:213.0     3rd Qu.:4750                3rd Qu.:2009  
#>                                  Max.   :59.60   Max.   :21.50   Max.   :231.0     Max.   :6300                Max.   :2009  
#>                                  NA's   :2       NA's   :2       NA's   :2         NA's   :2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut, that will be cleaner and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library(palmerpenguins)
summary(penguins)
```

Output of summary:

```
      species          island    bill_length_mm  bill_depth_mm   flipper_length_mm  body_mass_g  
 Adelie   :152   Biscoe   :168   Min.   :32.10   Min.   :13.10   Min.   :172.0     Min.   :2700  
 Chinstrap: 68   Dream    :124   1st Qu.:39.23   1st Qu.:15.60   1st Qu.:190.0     1st Qu.:3550  
 Gentoo   :124   Torgersen: 52   Median :44.45   Median :17.30   Median :197.0     Median :4050  
                                 Mean   :43.92   Mean   :17.15   Mean   :200.9     Mean   :4202  
                                 3rd Qu.:48.50   3rd Qu.:18.70   3rd Qu.:213.0     3rd Qu.:4750  
                                 Max.   :59.60   Max.   :21.50   Max.   :231.0     Max.   :6300  
                                 NA's   :2       NA's   :2       NA's   :2         NA's   :2     
     sex           year     
 female:165   Min.   :2007  
 male  :168   1st Qu.:2007  
 NA's  : 11   Median :2008  
              Mean   :2008  
              3rd Qu.:2009  
              Max.   :2009
```